# python flask request hook

Tags: python, flask, request

I want to be able to add some data into the `request` variable in flask for all incoming `requests`. Is there an easy way to hook into this without having to write this logic into each one of my endpoints?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You may be looking for [`flask.Flask.before_request`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.Flask.before_request).

Also you won't necessarily be able to add data into the `request` attributes `form` and `args` as they are immutable, consider using [`g`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.g) which is a [thread local](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/design/#thread-locals).

Example usage:

```
from flask import Flask, request, g

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return g.target + '\n'

@app.before_request
def before_req():
    g.target = request.args.get('target', 'default')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Usage:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:5000/?target=value'
value
$ curl 'http://localhost:5000/?key=value'
default
```

Comment: Thanks. I came across before_request previously, but I mistakenly thought it was a decorator you attached to each single route, hence the question.

Comment: That's alright, I updated the answer with a quick example, in case anyone else might need it.